# Invoke method with parameters

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, reflection

I have a problem with reflection.

The very essence: there is a bunch of methods in the class. I find it necessary this way (it's all good here):

```
invokingMethod = InstanceClass.getMethod(AMethodName, AArgumentTypes);
```

Then I want to call him:

```
result = invokingMethod.invoke(AInstance, AArgumentObjects);
```

The number of parameters can be different. Here, simply calling the authorization method and therefore only two parameters

Signature of the method:

```
public abstract long userLogin(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
```

Content AArgumentsTypes:

[image]

Content AArgumentObjects:

[image]

And as a result I have an error about the wrong type of parameters passed.

Works only if you explicitly pass all parameters to a function. Or I use AArgumentObjects[1] in the debug menu variable (if I change it in the code, the errors remain):

[image]

After calling from the code with AArgumentObjects[1]:

Discharges : "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException"
[image]

```
24-Jul-2017 14:21:08.444 SEVERE [http-nio-8081-exec-3] ru.nahodka.general.Reflection.TReflexiveClassUtils.invokeMethod java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
24-Jul-2017 14:21:08.444 INFO [http-nio-8081-exec-3] org.directwebremoting.log.accessLog.writeExceptionToAccessLog Method execution failed: 
 ru.nahodka.Applications.WebApplication.TCustomizableWebApplicationAbstractBothPart$WebServiceMethodInvokedException: Не удалось произвести вызов функции UserLogin в интерфейсе ru.nahodka.Family.Constants.FamilyClientMainInterfaceConstants.FamilyIntf. Код ошибки rwsrProcedureSuccess. 
    at ru.nahodka.ISUpravlenie.Implementation.ClientPart.MainInterfaceServiceInvoker.ControlLowLevelMainFunctionalClass.UserLogin(ControlLowLevelMainFunctionalClass.java:118)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at ru.nahodka.general.Reflection.TReflexiveUtils.InvokeMethodWithParameters(TReflexiveUtils.java:729)
    at ru.nahodka.ISUpravlenie.Implementation.ClientPart.AbstractFunctional.ControlHighLevelAbstractFunctionalClientClass.getLowLevelMethodInvokeResult(ControlHighLevelAbstractFunctionalClientClass.java:170)
    at ru.nahodka.ISUpravlenie.Implementation.ClientPart.MainInterfaceServiceInvoker.ControlHighLevelMainFunctionalClass.UserLogin(ControlHighLevelMainFunctionalClass.java:208)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.directwebremoting.impl.CreatorModule$1.doFilter(CreatorModule.java:178)
    at org.directwebremoting.impl.CreatorModule.executeMethod(CreatorModule.java:184)
    at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter.execute(DefaultRemoter.java:353)
    at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter.execute(DefaultRemoter.java:306)
    at org.directwebremoting.dwrp.BaseCallHandler.handle(BaseCallHandler.java:110)
    at org.directwebremoting.servlet.UrlProcessor.handle(UrlProcessor.java:211)
    at org.directwebremoting.servlet.UrlProcessor.handle(UrlProcessor.java:185)
    at org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet.doPost(DwrServlet.java:144)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1489)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean? Do you want to call the method with the wrong number or wrong type of parameters? That will not work.

Comment: Can you write `AMethodName` signature?

Comment: @Thilo, I want to call a method with those parameters that are in AArgumentObjects[1]. And since I can get the method I need, I just need to determine how to correctly pass parameters to it. Array type Object does not help.

Comment: Please share `AArgumentTypes` and `AArgumentObjects`, as those two have to be compatible.

Comment: @VadimBeskrovnov, 
public abstract long userLogin(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)

Comment: @Izruo, okey, i update post

Comment: `AArgumentObjects[1]` seems to be what should be passed to `invokingMethod.invoke`. Do you have the error message of the `IllegalArgumentException`?

Comment: Also include the full stack trace.

Comment: @Izruo, Thilo


Add error message and stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem this way, thank you all:

```
 result = invokingMethod.invoke(AInstance, ((Object[])AArgumentObjects[1]));
```